# Bazel + Kotlin + allopen plugin doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, bazel, intellij-plugin

I have Bazel build config:

```
...

load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:core.bzl", "define_kt_toolchain", "kt_compiler_plugin", "kt_kotlinc_options")
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:jvm.bzl", "kt_javac_options", "kt_jvm_library")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

kt_compiler_plugin(
    name = "allopen",
    compile_phase = True,
    id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.allopen",
    options = {
        "annotation": "plugin.allopen.OpenForTesting",
        "preset": "spring",
    },
    stubs_phase = True,
    deps = [
        "@com_github_jetbrains_kotlin//:allopen-compiler-plugin",
    ],
)

...
```

After running sync or even building IDEA still show me a hint that I need to set Class as Open.

[screen](https://ibb.co/RjtDjgd)

What I'm doing wrong? Please, gurus of Bazel, help me :)

Comment: Seems to be related to this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19474/Spring-false-positive-Classes-annotated-could-be-implicitly-subc

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov, are you sure that it's related to my problem? I thought that reason is because of bazel. When I used the same plugin with Gradle everything was ok.